# Dynamics pulley question - Clarification of answer. (SOLVED)

Tags: solution-verification, physics, classical-mechanics

I need some direction in solving this simple pulley problem.

*Two masses of $m$ and $2m$ kg are connected by a light inextensible string passing over a smooth pulley.  Find the acceleration of the system.
If the mass $2m$ kg hits the ground (without rebounding) after the masses have been moving 3 seconds, find how much time elapses from the instant this happens until the system is instantaneously at rest with the string taught.*

Finding the acceleration is straight forward using Newton's Second Law $F = ma$.  The acceleration is $a=\dfrac{g}{3} m/s^2$.  This is the book's answer.

My answer to the second part is $2\,s$.  However, the books answer is $3\,s$.

My logic is thus: the velocity of the $m$ mass after $3\,s$ is

$$
v = u + at
$$

$$ 
v = 0 + \frac{g}{3} \cdot 3
$$

$$ v = g $$

The $m$ kg mass moves upwards with an initial velocity of $g\,m/s$.  It temporarily comes to rest at its highest point when $v = 0$.

$$
 0 = g - gt
$$

$$
t = 1
$$

Total time is $2 \,s$, $1 \,s$ up and $1 \,s$ down.  At which the string is taught instantaneously.

I seem to doing something wrong...

Update on this problem.

Thanks to ABC the 'second' part of this problem (finding this illusive extra second) involves Impulsive String Tension. (https://mathspanda.com/A2FM/Lessons/Impulsive_tension_in_strings_LESSON.pdf).  As the mass $m$ returns to its position when the $2m$ hits the ground, impulsive string tension is now involved.

Using the conservation of linear momentum $mg = (m + 2m)v$, where $v$ is the velocity at which $m$ and $2m$ will move and $g$ is the velocity of $m$. When the taut string starts moving both $m$ and $2m$ have an initial velocity of $\dfrac{g}{3}$. The acceleration of the system is $\dfrac{-g}{3}$ (I found this using Newton's 2nd Law - just the reverse of the acceleration initially found).  Then, using $v = u + at$ for the $2m$ mass:

$$
v = u + at
$$
The $2m$ mass will come to instantaneous rest when $v = 0$.

$$
0 = \frac{g}{3} - \frac{g}{3} t
$$

$$
t = 1
$$

$ \therefore \Sigma t = 2 + 1 = 3\,sec$.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the question. What you are trying to find is the time it takes to tighten the string instantaneously. But the question is how long it takes for the string to come to *rest* instantaneously when it is taut.  As you have found, the string tightens in two seconds. Then the system starts moving under a deceleration(considering upward motion of 2m) with a different velocity. It takes another second from there to come to rest instantaneously. (Check it yourself.)

Comment: Thanks ABC.... I didn't consider this at all.  So here is my thought, if you can confirm my logic.  When the $m$ mass returns to it's taut' position 2 seconds have elapsed.  It returns to this position with a velocity of $g$  (since its initial velocity was also $g$).  This means the $2m$ mass has an initial velocity of $g$ and starts moving in an upward direction (as the $m$ moves in a downward direction).  The $2m$ mass comes to instantaneous rest when $v=0$, using $v = u + at \therefore 0 = g - gt, t = 1$.  So total time is 3 seconds.

Comment: @stephen, sorry it's not correct. The initial velocity of $2m$ is not $g$, because the string tightens instantaneously, you may use $I=\Delta(mv)$ to find it. Also after that, the acceleration is not $g$ because it's the same old system, so...

Comment: Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Well, I've had another attempt, this time finding the acceleration of the system as $\dfrac{-g}{3}$.  Since the motion is now in the opposite direction.  This doesn't really get me anywhere... So any more help is appreciated.  I think I am overlooking something that is really simple!

Comment: Ok, you really don't have to find the acceleration again since you've already found that. Hint: because of the jerk after 2s, there will be an impulsive tension in the string. Now apply $I=\Delta(mv)$ to the two masses and eliminate $I$. Btw, this question is not about mathematics, but physics.

Comment: Thank-you so much ABC.  Impulsive string tension is new to me but I found this great explanation (https://mathspanda.com/A2FM/Lessons/Impulsive_tension_in_strings_LESSON.pdf).  Using the conservation of linear momentum $mg = (m + 2m)v$  where $v$ is the velocity at which $m$ and $2m$ will move, and $g$ is the velocity of $m$.  I found that $2m$ has an initial velocity of $\dfrac{g}{3}$.  Then using $v = u + at$, the time taken for  $2m$ to come to instantaneous rest using  $\dfrac{-g}{3}$ as the acceleration, is $t = 1 \,s \therefore \Sigma t = 2 + 1 = 3\,s$.

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is that the answer in the book is wrong. I get the same answer using the fact that the string is taught when the object of mass $m$ is at the same position as when $2m$ stops.
$$0=\Delta y=vt-\frac12gt^2\\t=\frac{2v}g=2s$$

Comment: I have a different perspective, please read my comment above.